# Cannot get Snap.svg to select the proper svg element in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, snap.svg

I'm trying to get [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) to work in my Rails project.

I have a page `foo.html.slim` containing the following code:

```
#svg-container
  svg#apple height="1000" width="400"
```

And in `static_pages.js.coffee`, I have

```
svgElement = document.getElementById("apple")
paper = Snap(svgElement)
circ = paper.circle(100, 100, 50)
circ.attr
  fill: "#ff0000"
  stroke: "#0000ff"
  strokeWidth: 10
circ.drag()
```

This doesn't render the SVG anywhere on the page (the element isn't in the html source anywhere); however, if I add a line in a particular place like so

```
svgElement = document.getElementById("apple")
document.write("foo") # this is the new line
paper = Snap(svgElement)
circ = paper.circle(100, 100, 50)
circ.attr
  fill: "#ff0000"
  stroke: "#0000ff"
  strokeWidth: 10
circ.drag()
```

A red and blue circle gets drawn. The problem is it is at the very top of the body of the html rather than in the svg element that it should have selected. Also of note, if the `document.write("foo")` line is placed in a different position in the coffeescript file, the circle doesn't get drawn.

Neither also does `paper = Snap("#apple")` work instead of the original code.

What is the proper way to have the svg circle drawn in the existing svg element?

Comment: Do you need a `$ ->` wrapper to make sure `#apple` is around when you go looking for it?

Comment: Yes, `svgElement` is null when the javascript tries to access it. What exactly do i need to wrap up as a function? Just to check, I put a button on the page that calls the entirety of the javascript code. This does work, but only when I put the function definition directly into the html, but not when the javascript is on the Rails assets tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to access `#apple` before it is there. The easiest solution is wrap the code that needs `#apple` in a document-ready handler, in CoffeeScript that would look like this:

```
$ ->
  svgElement = document.getElementById("apple")
  paper = Snap(svgElement)
  circ = paper.circle(100, 100, 50)
  circ.attr
    fill: "#ff0000"
    stroke: "#0000ff"
    strokeWidth: 10
  circ.drag()
```

That's the same as [`$(function() { ... })`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) in JavaScript.